# JQuery DatePicker inside two asp.net grids on same screen

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have page in which there are multiple grids. Each control has a textbox bound with a JQuery `Datepicker`. I have the `beforeShow` event bound to show the datepicker under the textbox. The main problem is that when page renders the jquery datepicker calendar shows under the last textbox which is bound to datepicker even if I click on first textbox.

Thanks in advance,

Ali